# Process after grid was loaded completely using ExtJS

Tags: gridview, extjs, event-handling, extjs4

I am using ExtJS to load data to a grid, and I want to add some additional processes after data was put on grid completely.

My context is, after data was put on grid, I will check all rows, and mark some of them as disabled based on a specified condition and put tooltip to row (explain why it is disabled). I tried to use 2 events: 'afterrender' of Grid, and 'load' of grid's store, but they did not work.

Because `grid's 'afterrender'` was fired when first grid initialization, not concern to data load. `store's 'load'` was fired when data was prefetch to store (not render on screen), so I cannot get the row `<div>` to style it as disabled.

So, what is the event to detect when data was loaded and rendered completely on grid? And how can I implement this requirement?

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using? I think you're trying to solve your problem from a wrong angle.

Comment: I'm using ExtJS 4.0.1, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for you task you don't need to wait until grid is loaded but rather use `viewConfig` option for the grid panel to configure how exactly to display your rows:

```
viewConfig: {
   getRowClass: function(r) {
      if (r.get('disabled'))
         return 'disabled-class';
      else 
         return '';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried [`viewready`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-event-viewready)?

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // ...
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            viewready: function(view) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In ExtJS 4.0.7, this event appears to fire before the store is loaded, not after.

Comment: Using ExtJS 5.1 here, it seems to do the job.
According to the API description:
*Fires when the View's item elements representing Store items has been rendered. No items will be available for selection until this event fires.*
So it is my understanding this should happen after the store is load, and matches what I can see on the screen.

Answer (score 5):

You could tap into the store's `load` event directly, or relay the event through the grid.

Inside the grid class, probably in the `initComponent` function, put the following,

```
this.relayEvents(this.getStore(), [ 'load' ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `setTimeout` function it will force the call to happen after the rendering has finished, it worked in a similar case I had to yours.

```
listeners: {
     'afterrender': function(grid) {
          setTimeout(function(){
          // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but I recently had to fix a scrolling issue in an old ExtJS (4.0.2) app and I needed a trigger/event for when html (e.g. <table> tag) was actually updated/inserted in the grid view.

The following script adds new "update" event to Ext.grid.View. The update event is fired after html has been inserted into the view.

```
(function(){
    var _setNewTemplate = Ext.grid.View.prototype.setNewTemplate; 
    Ext.override(Ext.grid.View, {
        setNewTemplate: function(){

            _setNewTemplate.apply(this, arguments);

            var view = this;
            var template = this.tpl;
            template.overwrite = function(el, values, returnElement){ 
                el = Ext.getDom(el);
                el.innerHTML = template.applyTemplate(values);
                view.fireEvent("update", view, el); //<--New Event!
                return returnElement ? Ext.get(el.firstChild, true) : el.firstChild;
            };

            template.doInsert = function(where, el, values, returnEl) {
                el = Ext.getDom(el);
                var newNode = Ext.core.DomHelper.insertHtml(where, el, template.applyTemplate(values));
                view.fireEvent("update", view, el); //<--New Event!
                return returnEl ? Ext.get(newNode, true) : newNode;
            }

        }
    });
})();
```

To use the new event, you simply add a new event listener to the grid view. Example:

```
paymentGrid.view.on("update", function(view, el){ //vs paymentGrid.store.on("load", ...

    //do something...
    console.log(el);

}, this);
```

Note that this was implemented using ExtJS 4.0.2. You may need to update the script for your version of ExtJS.

**UPDATE**

I found that the new "update" event was not firing when a view was rendering an empty store. As a workaround, I extended the view's refresh method.

```
(function(){
    var _refresh = Ext.grid.View.prototype.refresh;
    Ext.override(Ext.grid.View, {
        refresh: function() {
            _refresh.apply(this, arguments);                

            var view = this;
            var el = view.getTargetEl();
            var records = view.store.getRange();

            if (records.length < 1) {                    
                view.fireEvent("update", view, el); //<--New Event!
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the success: property on getForm().load() to call a function to handle post load processing

Answer (score 0):

`viewready` worked for me !!!

Configured as below in controller :

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Dashboard', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#summary-bottom-grid': {
            viewready: function(cmp){
                var link = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('span.summary-status',cmp.body.dom);
            }
          }
     });    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use extjs 4.2.3 and this worked.

I used this:

```
this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
     store: this.ds,
     margins: '0 0 0 10', // top right button left
     title: lng.menu.caption.mailHeaderGrid,
     selType: 'checkboxmodel',
     columns:[...],
     selModel: {
         renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
             var baseCSSPrefix = Ext.baseCSSPrefix;
             metaData.tdCls = baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-special ' + baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-row-checker';
             return (record.get('status') =='lng.label.surveyFinalized') ? '' : '<div class="' + baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-row-checker"> </div>';
         },
     },
```

For me works on chrome!

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?237641-How-to-hide-certain-checkbox-in-a-CheckboxSelectionModel