# Get time required to load data into grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, profiling, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJS 4.1. I want to capture the time required to load data into an grid panel. For this, I have added listener on `beforerender` event and `afterrender` event of grid but `afterrender` event is fired before data is loaded and displayed into the grid.

So I am not able to capture the actual time needed to load the data. I saw [this similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222295/process-after-grid-was-loaded-completely-using-extjs)  but it didn't helped me. As mentioned in that question, `load` event of store does not help because `load` event of store fires before that data is rendered into cells of grid.

So can anyone please tell how to capture the exact time required to load data into grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all events you are interested in get fired by the view and not by the grid. I think the following events are interesting for you:

- **[beforerefresh](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-event-beforerefresh)** *fired before the rendering of the content starts*
- **[refresh](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-event-refresh)** *fired when the rendering of the content finished*

```
viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        beforerefresh: function() {
            alert('before');
        },
        refresh: function() {
            alert('on(after)')
        }
    }
}
```